# What's the email limit of a sandbox org?

Tags: email

What's the email limit of a sandbox org? I'm unable to find any information on this in salesforce's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a daily limit of 1000 single and 1000 mass emails in sandbox.
You can check it yourself by going to workbench and logging with your sandbox credentials, Then do a GET request fot the limits like this:

```
/services/data/v37.0/limits
```

Please let me knnow if this helps.

Comment: Please mark as best answer if it helped. This will help the rest of the community should they have a similar issue in the future. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

> - You can send mass email to a maximum of 1,000 external email addresses per day per org based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
>
>   - *Even if it is 1000(Unlimited Edition), it is lower for  Professional(250), Enterprise(500) orgs .*

Salesforce standard documentation,

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_email.htm
2. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Checking-the-SingleEmailMessage-limit&language=en_US